# print every row in excel to separate page in word

Tags: excel, printing, ms-word

I have a list of cheque records in excel (amount, name, amount in word and date), I want to print every cheque record on a separate page and different aliment.

Comment: Mail merge is the best option for this task. Search on google for mail merge.

Comment: https://helpdesk.concord.edu/kb/article/122-how-to-do-a-mail-merge-in-word-using-an-excel-spreadsheet/